# linq query with condition

Tags: c#, linq

I'm writing a linq query in query syntax and I'm wondering how to add another where clause.
Basically, I have the following:

```
var test = from t in MyDC.TheTable
           where t.UserID == TheUserID
           where t.DateDone.Date == TheDate.Date
           select new MyModel {.....};
```

TheTable has a column called LinkedID and this column is also in another table called ColorStatus (a number between 1 and 10). I'm looking to write the where clause "where the LinkedID in the ColorStatus table is less than 7".

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your information "another table called ColorStatus" doesn't make sense here.

```
var test = from t in MyDC.TheTable
           where t.UserID == TheUserID
              && t.DateDone.Date == TheDate.Date
              && t.LinkedID < 7           
           select new MyModel {.....};
```

Probably I didn't get your idea, here is an example of `join` may help you.

```
var test = from t in MyDC.TheTable
           join x in MyDC.ColorStatus
           on t.LinkedID == x.LinkedID
           where t.UserID == TheUserID
              && t.DateDone.Date == TheDate.Date
              && x.AnotherField == 1
           select new MyModel {.....};
```

Answer (score 4):

Just a suggestion on improving the statement you have. You can actually merge the two where conditions into a single one. `&&` means "AND"

```
Where t.UserID == TheUserID && t.DateDone.Date = TheDate.Date
```

Comment: ok, thanks, I'll make the change. I'm still working on adding the final where clause.